# Dates Looping Incorrectly in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the following code in Access VBA:

```
Public Sub CalculateVol()

Dim vol As Double
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim rs2 As Recordset
Dim rs3 As Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim MaxOfMarkAsofDate As Date
Dim userdate As String

DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM HolderTable"

DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM volTable"
'Clears out the old array from the holder table.

Dim dateCounter As Integer
Dim count As Integer
Dim x As Date

userdate = InputBox("Please Enter the Date (mm/dd/yyyy)")

x = userdate

Dim BucketTermAmt As Long
BucketTermAmt = InputBox("Please Enter the Term Amount")

Do While count < 78

MaxOfMarkAsofDate = x - dateCounter


MaturityTermCount = 3

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM RiskMetricsOutput WHERE MaturityTermCount=" & MaturityTermCount & " AND MaxOfMarkAsofDate=#" & MaxOfMarkAsofDate & "# ORDER BY MaxOfMarkasOfDate"


Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, Type:=dbOpenDynaset, Options:=dbSeeChanges)
Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("HolderTable")
Set rs3 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("volTable")


If rs.RecordCount <> 0 Then

    rs.MoveFirst

    rs.MoveLast


    Dim BucketTermUnit As String
    Dim BucketDate As Date
    Dim MarkAsOfDate As Date
    Dim InterpRate As Double


    Dim b As String

    b = BucketTermAmt

    BucketTermUnit = "m"
    BucketDate = DateAdd(BucketTermUnit, b, MaxOfMarkAsofDate)
    InterpRate = CurveInterpolateRecordset(rs, BucketDate)

    rs2.AddNew
    rs2("BucketDate") = MaxOfMarkAsofDate
    rs2("InterpRate") = InterpRate
    rs2.Update

count = count + 1


End If

dateCounter = dateCounter + 1



vol = EWMA(0.94) * 1.65

rs3.AddNew
rs3("MaxofMarkasofDate") = MaxofMarkasofDate
rs3("Vols") = vol
rs3.Update

Debug.Print MaxOfMarkAsofDate, vol

Loop

End Sub
```

The basic idea is that the user inputs a date for MaxofMarkAsofDate. The code then finds that instance of MarkAsofDate in the table RiskMetricsOutput, and uses it as a reference point to calculate InterpRate. It stores this number in the HolderTable.

Then it loops the same procedure, except using one day previous to the user-inputted MarkAsofDate, and then one day previous to that, and so on for a total of 78 times.

It then uses those InterpRates to calculate a simple volatility, and stores the volatility and the relevant date in the table called VolTable.

All of this works fine, and it gets the correct volatility number. However, the dates are backwards in the VolTable and I can't figure out why. If I input a date of 8/20/2015, for example, I'll see the correct volatility in the table, except the associated MarkasofDate will be 4/30/2015. And it will appear as the last date, not the first. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit - the recordsets**

The RiskMetrics output record is formatted like this, going back to 2000:

```
BucketID    MaxOfMarkAsOfDate   PriceVolatility MarkRunID    MaturityTermCount  MaturityDate    UnderlyingValue
CA.CAD.GDB      2/26/2016      0.006033          10704              3           5/26/2016        0.461
CA.CAD.GDB      2/25/2016      0.006033          10705              3           5/25/2016        0.47
CA.CAD.GDB      2/24/2016      0.006033          10706              3           5/24/2016        0.465
    CA.CAD.GDB      2/23/2016      0.006033          10707              3           5/23/2016        0.463
```

The output table volTable looks like this:

```
MaxOfMarkAsofDate   Vols
8/20/2015          0.0375
8/19/2015          0.0398
8/18/2015          0.0344
8/17/2015          0.0323
8/16/2015          0.0311

....


5/4/2015            0.01313
5/3/2015            0.01123
5/2/2015            0.01564
5/1/2015            0.01709
4/30/2015           0.01706
```

The problem is that the output is backwards: 0.01706 should be the number for 8/20/2015, and 0.0375 should be the number for 4/30/2015.

Comment: Is this a sorting issue?  Are all the correct dates in there, but just in the wrong order?

Comment: Yeah it's a sorting issue pretty much - the dates go from last to first and the numbers go from first to last. I want to reverse the order of the dates essentially.

Comment: So why can't you just use ORDER BY when you're displaying/editing the data later?  It doesn't really matter which order they're in when the data is in the table.  You're working backwards with your data, so of course the last date you write is actually going to be the earliest date in the dataset.

Comment: how would I reverse the order of the date in the table without also reversing the vol number associated with the date? if there's a way to do that that would solve the problem, not sure how to order it by date without changing the order of the associated numbers as well though

Comment: Count the vol numbers backwards too?  Without seeing the base data, it's hard to know.

Comment: what would I need to change in order to count the vol numbers backwards? thank you

Comment: We don't have enough information here.  Some SO questions are easy (i.e., "How do I get the year if given a date?"), they're based on standard coding.  This question involves specific data, and since you haven't posted any data, it's near impossible to know exactly what's causing the issue.  Even if you just posted 5 or 6 records from each table, including your results table, it'd be pretty easy to spot what's going wrong.  Also, apparently we only have part of the code, and the problem may be caused by code that hasn't even been posted.

Comment: Ah okay, I understand. I added some records to maybe clarify. Again, thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Still not really clear what's going on.  Is strSQL what is writing the data to VolTable?  If so, I would put a breakpoint on it, find out the exact SQL it resolves to, and then put that in a new query window to see if you can see why it's writing the wrong date with the right Vol.  It doesn't make any sense that the two columns in the same table are in opposite order.  You need to pull this apart on a granular level, look at each table write and see what exactly is getting written record by record.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust these lines:

```
x = CDate(userdate)

Dim BucketTermAmt As Long
BucketTermAmt = Val(InputBox("Please Enter the Term Amount"))

Do While count < 78

    MaxOfMarkAsofDate = DateAdd("d", -dateCounter, x)
```

Also this - and add Desc for reverse order:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM RiskMetricsOutput WHERE MaturityTermCount = " & MaturityTermCount & " AND MaxOfMarkAsofDate = #" & Format(MaxOfMarkAsofDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# ORDER BY MaxOfMarkasOfDate Desc"
```

Further, you may have to rename the variable `MaxOfMarkAsofDate` to not conflict with the field name.

Comment: thanks I fixed the code but it's still producing the same sorting issue - the order of the dates remains the same

Comment: Can't tell, but see addendum.

Comment: hmm it's still giving it to me in the same order which is very strange. is there any way to just reverse the first column of dates without changing the associated column of numbers?

Comment: A table has per definition no order. To display the records in some order , use a select query.